# Token based Web Site logins?

Tags: php, c++

I'm really not sure how this works and can't seem to find much info on it.

I play a PC exe game where I can be logged in in-game. I then click the store button. It opens my browser. I see some token stuff in the url then it logs me in to the site with my profile and everything.

How would something like this typically work or be implemented?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are logged in to the game, you can make requests to the game server as an authenticated user. Your game client makes on your behalf a request to generate a login token, that is tied to your user.

The token is basically a pair consisting of your user ID + a random string. This pair can be stored anywhere on the game system's servers (mySQL database, memcached server, redis server, text file??). Most often, an expiry time will be associated with the token. If using something like redis or memcached, expiry time is inherent to the system. If using mySQL or a regular file, the expiry time can be defined as an additional field.

When you go to the provided URL, the token in the URL is passed to the web server, which in turn passes it to whatever is driving your dynamic website (php, python, nginx, whatever).

The dynamic scripting language will go check that token against the database where it was stored, see that it's associated with your user, and let you login. Since these tokens are mostly one-time use, the system will also destroy the token the first time it is used.